# Ansible 2.7.10 got error with communication with rabbitmq 3.8.7

Tags: windows, powershell, ansible, rabbitmq, ansible-2.x

I have Ansible 2.7.10 with python 3.6.7 on Ubuntu, RabbitMQ 3.8.7 with Erlang 21.3 on Windows 2019 Core.

I want run simple task like:

> ansible rabbit -m rabbitmq_vhost -a "name=/test state=present"

```
172.25.222.105 | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "Exception calling \"Create\" with \"1\" argument(s): \"At line:4 char:21\r
+ def _ansiballz_main():\r
+                     ~\r
An expression was expected after '('.\r
At line:12 char:27\r
+     except (AttributeError, OSError):\r
+                           ~\r
Missing argument in parameter list.\r
At line:14 char:7\r
+     if scriptdir is not None:\r
+       ~\r
Missing '(' after 'if' in if statement.\r
At line:21 char:7\r
+     if sys.version_info < (3,):\r
+       ~\r
Missing '(' after 'if' in if statement.\r
At line:21 char:30\r
+     if sys.version_info < (3,):\r
+                              ~\r
Missing expression after ','.\r
At line:21 char:25\r
+     if sys.version_info < (3,):\r
+                         ~\r
The '<' operator is reserved for future use.\r
At line:23 char:32\r
+         MOD_DESC = ('.py', 'U', imp.PY_SOURCE)\r
+                                ~\r
Missing expression after ','.\r
At line:23 char:33\r
+         MOD_DESC = ('.py', 'U', imp.PY_SOURCE)\r
+                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r
Unexpected token 'imp.PY_SOURCE' in expression or statement.\r
At line:23 char:32\r
+         MOD_DESC = ('.py', 'U', imp.PY_SOURCE)\r
+                                ~\r
Missing closing ')' in expression.\r
At line:23 char:46\r
+         MOD_DESC = ('.py', 'U', imp.PY_SOURCE)\r
+                                              ~\r
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.\r
Not all parse errors were reported.  Correct the reported errors and try again.\"\r
At line:6 char:1\r
+ $exec_wrapper = [ScriptBlock]::Create($split_parts[0])\r
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException\r
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParseException\r
 \r
The expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an object that was not valid. It must result in a command name,\r
 a script block, or a CommandInfo object.\r
At line:7 char:2\r
+ &$exec_wrapper\r
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException\r
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadExpression\r
 ",
    "module_stdout": "",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE
See stdout/stderr for the exact error",
    "rc": 1
}
```

I also tested with different module like: rabbitmq_user, error is the same. I also tested with ansible 2.7.10 and python 2.6 and I received the same error, tests with playbook the same. In playbook I have also checking if rabbitmq service is up and running and this works fine except communication with rabbitmq.

inventory file:

```
[rabbit]
172.25.222.105
```

variables file:

```
ansible_user: ansible
ansible_password: password
ansible_port: 5985
ansible_connection: winrm
ansible_winrm_transport: ntlm
```

ansible user is local admin

Some suggestions how to talk with ansible and rabbitmq ? I don't have new ideas how to resolve that problem :(

Big thanks to all for your help.

Comment: Those errors appear to be coming from powershell (which ansible probably makes use of for executing tasks on a windows host, but I'm not all that familiar with ansible on windows). Are other ansible tasks working correctly? Is it just the rabbitmq modules that are having this problem?

Comment: Other tasks, like check if rabbit service working, works fine, only task with rabbit doesn't works.

Comment: What does the inventory entry for your "rabbit" host (or group) look like? (you should add this to your question, rather than leaving a comment)